# Как при клике на слайдер изменить стилевой файл в index?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача заключается в том, чтобы при клике на слайдер подменивался стилевой файл в html, скопипастил основной стилевой файл и поменял ему название со style.css на style_green.css, получается при клике на слайдер некоторые элементы сайта станут салатового оттенка, в js пока новичок поэтому никак не могу разобраться как это реализовать. Идея есть, а реализация хромает. Ниже код слайдера.

```
<div class="theme-changer position-absolute">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                              </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
.theme-changer {
    left: -100%;
    top: 40%;
    width: max-content;
    z-index: 10;
}
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
  .switch input {display:none;}
  
  /* The slider */
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```
let switchTheme = document.querySelector('.slider.round');
let navLogo = document.querySelector('.nav-logo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте стили для "салатового оттенка" в тот же файл и при клике меняйте class, а не файл.

```js
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('slider').setAttribute("class", "style-after");
}
```

```css
.style-before{
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:40px;
    height:20px;
}

.style-after{
    background-color:#99ff99;
    width:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="style-before"><span onclick="myFunction()">Slider</span></div>
```